# Error using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I want to extract some data from a website. I saved it as 'Webpage, HTML Only', in a file called soccerway.html on my Desktop.

Afterwards I wrote the following command using an IPython notebook:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(open("soccerway.html"))
```

I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'soccerway.html'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup, of course. The `open()` call won't work either way.

Comment: You need to use an absolute path; your script's current working directory is not the Desktop folder.

Comment: Better still, use *Python* to download the page instead..

Comment: you need to provide correct path if you want to parse local files

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you! I tried that but I forgot to escape the backslash character and therefore it way giving me the error. Now it's all working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually save a page. Use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to get the html source you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://my_site.com/mypage"))
```

Example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://google.com'))
>>> soup('a')
[<a class="gb1" href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&amp;tab=wi">Images</a>, 
 ...
]
```

Comment: Going back to the OP's question: how do you accomplish this by loading a  file? And yes, it can be done with a URL - but what about a file?

Comment: @zero_cool yup, you can, of course, use the `open()` function and provide a correct path to the local HTML file ([example](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open("yourfile.html", "r")

soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "html.parser")
```

Comment: And how does it answer the question?

Comment: @mx0 This is the solution, or more precisely, correct way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is a correct way but it doesn't solve the problem OP is having `No such file or directory`. It's a good answer for a wrong question and it's now marked as a low quality answer.